# Distribute offset in Set Position relative to face direction | Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I am making ice-cream in Blender 3.1.2 with procedural topping and this is how it looks like half-the way poured on top. I tried to add some noise in offset to imitate peanuts in the topping. My problem is that with my current setup noise is only added in one oblique axis, not around the whole topping.

Clean Ice-cream topping:
[image]

Noise applied: (A little bit increased for the issue to be clearer for you)
[image]

Basically I would love to have this pikes all over the topping, facing outwards, like a dog toy ball.

Here is my node setup:
[image]
You may be rather interested in the lower half of nodes, but I am sharing whole picture.
Upper half is for procedural topping itself, lower is for noise for imitating peanuts.

I would appreciate any help or tips! :D
Anyone have a idea what to do?

Comment: You are intermixing vectors and normal math nodes. each time you connect a vector into a math node it becomes a singular float value. So the voronoi texture loses it's 3Dimensionality at the power operation and your normal node loses it's 3Dimensionaliity as soon as its pluged into the math node. Change those to vector math nodes.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot!